# Nativescript angular element parse error: Error : invalid attribute [(ngModel)]

Tags: xml, angular, nativescript

Nativescript angular app error:

> element parse error: Error : invalid attribute [(ngModel)].

Project created using a template "nativescript-template-ng-tutorial" but on using angular tags such as `[(ngModel)]` or `*ngFor`, I get:

> element parse error: Error : invalid attribute [(ngModel)].

Already imported the NativeScriptFormsModule from nativescript-angular/forms.

This is my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptFormsModule, FormsModule],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is a snapshot of the error: 
[Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bObJa.png)

Comment: There's a bit too little to go on here I think. Could you update the question with a basic but exact set of steps to reproduce the error please?

Comment: Can you upload a playground ? Also did you import the common module ? Upload the code for your app module and the relevant files

Comment: I'm new to both NativeScript and Angular, please tell which common module are you referring to @Royi Namir

Comment: upload your code @JayeshGoyal

Comment: Just changed the extension of app.component.xml to app.component.html and the errors vanished. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the extension of app.component.xml to app.component.html and no errors occur. This is because angular tags are not recognized for XML file types.
For reference read the TIP from the following link : https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3